# CSS <link> mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

My mod_rewrite will not work and can not solve the problem. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

My mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^/([^/.]+)/?$    index.php?g=$1    [L]
```

My CSS File is linked like below

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="/includes/libs/minify/index.php?g=responsive.css&amp;319" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>
```

I want to change it with mod_rewrite to

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and how does it not work? What do you get when you try to open that URL?

Comment: I want to change url to `<link href="responsive.css">`

Comment: I don't think that fully explains the situation. Please clarify what you are trying to do and what is not working.

Comment: Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html, the first section "old to new"